# Payload CMS won't connect to mongo DB

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I'm trying to get [Payload CMS](https://payloadcms.com/) up and running and when I run `npm run dev` I run into an error that says

> ERROR (payload): Error: cannot connect to MongoDB. Details: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I installed mongo on my machine locally and left the *Run service as Network Service User* selected and opted out of installing Mongo Compass.  In Payload's setup it asks for the path for our mongo database.  On mongo afer setting up a new database I chose the *connect to your app* option and copied this snippet

> mongodb+srv://my_db_name:@my_name.something.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority

and pasted it in where the Payload setup asks for it.  inside my project I have a `.env` file which looks like this

```
MONGODB_URI = mongodb+srv://my_db_name:my_password@my_name.something.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
PAYLOAD_SECRE = my_super_long_secret_key_thats_not_this
```

Now I did notice there weren't any quotes around the values so I added some figuring maybe it needed to be forced into being a string and I still got the same error.  As far as I can tell my db name, password and domain are all there in the URI provided by the `.env` file. In the docs it says to run `node server.js` in order to start it, which in my case is `server.ts` because I'm using typescript but that didn't do anything.  I found a video by the creator who used `yarn dev` so I decided to try `npm run dev` to get it going and it seemed to start properly up until the connection to mongo failed.  Anyone have any clue as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

**Example:**
`mongodb://localhost/` -> `mongodb://127.0.0.1/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you create app with `npx create-payload-app`? If so, it's a good idea to run app with `npm run dev`. It has `PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH` variable in dev script - you can check this in `package.json` file.

You say that you are using the local MongoDB installation, but your `MONGODB_URI` looks like address to a MongoDB Atlas service.

1. MongoDB Atlas connection - If that's the case, check if you have granted access from your IP address to MongoDB Atlas - [Atlas connection guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/cloud/connectionstring/)
2. Local MongoDB installation - If you are for sure using the local database, then your address should look like this `mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017`

For local MongoDB management and connection tests you can use MongoDB Compass application - it's simple graphical tool.